# How to put the caret in the first cell when inserting a table in a WinForm RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf, caret

I'm making a not advanced text editor and one of its features is to insert a simple table.

Back then i could insert the table and `having the caret in the first cell` of the table but recently i updated my Windows 8.1 and also i got security update for .net.

Yesterday i continued to work on my project and realized that after i insert a table the caret no longer set in the first cell but on the top of the richtextbox at `index = 0`. I don't know if the update to .NET has anything to do to it or not.

Table insertion code:

```
var cellWidth = -1;
var rtf = new StringBuilder();
rtf.Append(@"{\rtf1 ");

cellWidth = 1000;
if (AutoSize)
{
   cellWidth = ((note_txt.ClientSize.Width - 3) / row) * 15;
}
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
{
    rtf.Append(@"\trowd");
    for (int j = 1; j <= row; j++)
    rtf.Append(@"\cellx" + (j * cellWidth));
    rtf.Append(@"\intbl \cell \row"); //create row
}
rtf.Append(@"\pard");
rtf.Append(@"}");

var rtf1 = rtf.ToString();
note_txt.SelectedRtf = rtf1;
```

then i put this

```
note_txt.SelectionStart = note_txt.Rtf.IndexOf(@"{\rtf1");
```

But when i put a brake point i can see that the `SelectionStart = 0` after that line. Why it stopped having the caret in the first cell.

The table get inserted successfully but where the caret set is where i have the problem, is there a way to put the caret in the first cell or simply let it set after the table?

Comment: Well, RTF text usually begins with `{\rtf1`, so, it's quite probable. If you already have some text in there, that string will be in the first position (at index `0`).

Comment: @Jimi Why '@"{\rtf1 "' that we added when we create the table doesn't appear in the rtf of the RichTextBox? Even if i used `note_txt.SelectionStart = note_txt.Rtf. **LastIndexOf** (@"{\rtf1");` I still get `index = 0`

Comment: Have you inspected the RTF of that RichTextBox after you have added that table? You cannot have more than one RTF boundary definition.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, `only once {\rtf1 exists`.
Thanks for helping. I will keep it that after inserting a table, the caret will be at the end of it.

Comment: Just do this: `int selStart = note_txt.SelectionStart;` add the Table, then `note_txt.SelectionStart = selStart + 1;`. `Rtf.IndexOf()` is not your friend here.

Comment: @jimi Very strange behavior, if i stored the `SelectionStart` value in `selStart` and then i added +1 to it after the table is created the new SelectionStart `will  be less than SelStart by one`. **Example**: if SelectionStart was on `10` after the table got created it is on `9` [can't find out why] but if i put this line `note_txt.SelectionStart = note_txt.Rtf.IndexOf(@"{\rtf1");` before `selStart + 1` it put the caret at the first cell as i want and `the new SelectionStart will be more than the old one by 2`. **Example**: If it was `10` the new one will be `12`.